# SQLite database with multi-valued properties

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a SQLITE database for storing objects. The objects have properties with multiple values for which I have created separate tables.

```
CREATE TABLE objs 
(
     id INTEGER, 
     name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE prop1 
(
     id INTEGER, 
     value TEXT, 
     FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES objs(id)
);

CREATE TABLE prop2 
( 
     id INTEGER, 
     value TEXT, 
     FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES objs(id)
);
```

For a list of *id*s I get as a result of JOINs, I want to find values of these two properties. For that, I am performing the JOINs followed by another JOIN with the 'prop1' table. I then repeat this for 'prop2' table. I suspect this is inefficient (too many joins) and can be improved. I have two questions.

1. Is this the correct way to design the DB ?
2. What is the most efficient way of extracting values of the properties I want ?

Comment: You probably don't need/want to have two separate properties tables.  Show us some sample data please.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the data is of the type that is stored on an LDAP server (rfc4519). The objects would have multi-valued attributes like telephoneNumber, member, postalAddress etc

Comment: Rahul, your comment doesn't really answer my question.  I agree with the answer given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE objs 
(
     id INTEGER, 
     name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE properties
(
     id INTEGER,
     Property_name varchar(50),
     Property_type varchar(10),
     value TEXT, 
     FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES objs(id)
);
```

Storing all the different types of properties in different table is a very bad idea. You can just store the property name and type(string, numeric etc.). You can also add multiple value columns like numeric_value, string_value and so on.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed much better than having multiple tables - one for each type of property. But I would still have a separate table for each syntax - integer, text, binary, boolean, reference etc. Because of that, I will have to perform one set of joins and select per syntax. Is it possible to do better ?